# Is it possible to make input act like a link (Chrome)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I want an `input type="button"` act like a link to the browser (so, it is possible to **right click** on the input and see **context menu** for the links(**open link in a new tab, open link in a new window etc**).
I have a form with a submit button:

```
<input type="submit" value="Run Query"/>
```

In order to create a link and **have** this **context-menu**, I replaced `input` with:

```
<a href="#" onclick="$(this).parent().submit(); return false;">Run Query</a>
```

But this way "open link in a new tab" opens the same page(due to the href attribute). 
I know that you can just ctrl+click on the `<input type="submit"/>` to open it in a new tab, but if the `input` tag is present, there is no context menu for it in Chrome. 
Is it possible to create an input that would have the same context menu as a link? Or any trick to tell the browser to add this functionality to the `input` tag?

Comment: What do you expect to see when you right click and link in a new tab"? Since it doesn't have a link.

Comment: you can't post to a new tab unless you use `target="_blank"` on the `form`

Comment: yes, link doesn't have a link, but my form does. I expect to submit the form and see the new page. It works only on left click now with <input/>/<a>.

Comment: @DavidFregoli I think you can post it by using Ctrl+Click on the input tag.

Comment: You mean, you want to go to the page from your `form` `action` attribute?

Comment: @putvande Yes, sorry if it was not clear from the question.

Comment: I really don't understand what you're trying to accomplish. Do you want the user to be able to enter a url and link to that url?

Comment: @sebbzzz I want my input tag to have the same context menu as a link(open link in a new tab, open link in a new window etc). But Now I am really close to believe that it is impossible:)

Comment: This sounds like an `X-Y` problem. Please explain full behavior you anticipate with regards to form submit and display. The form wouldn't submit using your right click concept without a non native context menu ( which can be implemented)

Comment: Yeah, I got that, but I don't think that is possible, but I meant to ask why you want this, maybe the task you're trying to achieve can be done in another way

Comment: @sebbzzz Actually I found a solution that you can just Ctrl+click on the input to open it in a new window. But some app users are old fashioned and ask me to implement this kind of behaviour to the input tag.

Comment: @charlietfl Yes, I think that is a great idea to create non-native context menu which will open form in a target=_blank fashion.Thanks! I suppose there is no other way.

Comment: @charlietfl You can put an answer so I can accept that. Or I can delete this question:) Your choice.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you want to submit the form to a new tab? 
Then you could use `target="_blank"` on the form element.

```
<form action="" method="POST" target="_blank" >
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: No actually I don't. I want an input type="button" act like a link to the browser (so, it is possible to right click on the input and see context menu for the links(open link in a new tab, open link in a new window etc)

Comment: I'm not sure that is possible, at least I don't know how to. So my answer is incorrect then?

Comment: Sorry, yes your answer is incorrect. As @charlietf l I think the only way is to create some js context menu for that.

Answer (score 0):

This will use the query string to pass the value of each input field to a new window or tab and submit it. It won't work if you're posting files (a workaround would be to immediately upload the file when selected, give it an id and store that in a hidden field, so the file id is the one being posted).

Note that this is an example and you should use something better for dealing with query strings and browser compatibility (it's only tested on Chrome). You should test it thoroughly in other browsers before shipping this! I also have no clue how it's going to work in browsers for iOS/Android/Windows Phones etc. What I'm trying to say is that you probably shouldn't use this.

```
<body>
<form action="http://google.com">
<input type="text" name="stuff" value="" />
<input type="text" name="q" value="" />
<a href="#">Submit</a>
</form>

<script>
!function () {
    var form = document.querySelector("form")
    var submitButton = document.querySelector("a")
    var queryString = location.search.slice(1).split("&").reduce(function (seed, str) {
        var pair = str.split("=")
        seed[pair[0]] = decodeURIComponent(pair[1])
        return seed
    }, {})

    Object.keys(queryString).forEach(function (qsKey) {
        var formEl = form.querySelector("[name='" + qsKey + "']")
        if(formEl)
            formEl.value = queryString[qsKey]
    })

    if(queryString.submit)
        form.submit()

    submitButton.addEventListener("contextmenu", updateHref) // Update on right click

    submitButton.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        if(e.altKey || e.ctrlKey || e.shiftKey || e.which === 2 /* middle mouse button */) {
            updateHref()
        } else {
            e.preventDefault()
            form.submit()
        }
    })

    function updateHref() {
        var values = [].slice.call(form.elements).map(function (el) {
            return el.name + "=" + encodeURIComponent(el.value)
        })
        submitButton.href = location.pathname + "?submit=1&" + values.join("&")
    }
}()
</script>
</body>
```